# Prevent title/toolbar inlining on macOS using wxPython

Tags: macos, wxpython, wxwidgets

With

```py
tb = myFrame.CreateToolBar()
tb.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'A', wx.Bitmap("plus.png"))
tb.AddStretchableSpace()
tb.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, 'B', wx.Bitmap("plus.png"))
tb.Realize()
```

I get
[image]

But I want
[image]

Except the second one uses `wx.FRAME_TOOL_WINDOW` just to prevent frame title inlining but can't be used for the main frame of an application. I know it's possible to prevent the inlining and make the `AddStretchableSpace` work because I've seen it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is the behavior OSX is defining right now.
You can try to look at wxUI...

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're right that they want inlining to be the go-to, but there _is_ a way around it. I've edited the question to show an example.

Comment: @sr3, if you are talking about Xcode, most likely they are using the old interface and will update soon. Take a look at all other native applications.

Comment: The Finder application has toolbar tools on the left side (back/forward arrows) and right side (search, etc.).